# Request from React.js app not hitting Node.js backend endpoint

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am making an `React` and `node` application.

`Node` is running on port `3001`.

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3001'); //in bin/www
```

`React` is configured with a proxy and is running on port 3000.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001", //in package.json
```

In `Node`,

`app.js` has route defined for `/`.

```
app.use('/', indexRouter); //a path  with / goes to indexRouter
```

`routes/index.js` passes the request to a controller.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
let index = require('../controllers/index');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', index.index);

module.exports = router;
```

`controllers/index.js` responds with a `json`

```
exports.index = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('index page'); //I DONT SEE THIS TRACE
    res.json({message: `some message` });
}
```

In `React`, `app.js`, send a request, awaits for response

```
import React from "react";
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(`got response ${res}`)
        res.json()}
        )
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(`data : ${data}`)
        setData(data.message)}
        );
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          {!data ? "Loading..." : data}
        </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run the app (`Node` first followed by `React`, I don't see the trace `console.log('index page');` which is in `controllers/index.js`.

I don't think the `react` message is reaching `node`. The traces in browser are:

```
App.js:12 got response [object Response]
App.js:16 data : undefined
App.js:17  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')
    at App.js:17:1
```

On further debugging, I found that the response to request is `304`.

The request is (to url `/question`)

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does network request in browser dev tools look like? And may be `router.get('/', index.index);` line should be `router.get('/', index);`

Comment: How do I see it in `Edge` browser? In `Chrome`, I see message `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app`

Comment: @ManuChadha https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/12654?hl=en, with this you  can enable js in chrome

Comment: it seems javascript is disabled in your Edge browser. Can you use google chrome or firefox?

Comment: I can try this. However, considering that I use the browser for everyday work, I'll be surprised that disabled `js` is the issue. How would I'll be able to use other website without any problem

Comment: `Sites can use Javascript` - already enabled in Chrome

Comment: The **only** issue I see here is that you're not returning the `res.json()` promise for the next step in the chain. That is why `data` is undefined. As for your Express logging, you would see that in the terminal where you start the service, not in the browser console

Comment: sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: You add `return` in front of it